# Why do we need both the pi0 and pi-zero tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently five questions tagged [pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero) and two questions tagged [pi0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi0). Which of these tags should be considered "canonical" for the [Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/)? I don't think there's a need for both of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't need both. Actually I wanted to creata a tag synonym. Turns out I can't... Unless

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.

But I guess we could go this far and just clear out [pi0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi0) and further retag question if it ever comes up again.

Comment: [200_success](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/27703/200-success) already swapped all the tags, but I've added the merge/synonym so it can't happen again.

Answer (score -1):

Um, the tags [pi1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi1) and [pi2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi2) are the "master" ones for those Pi versions - logically therefore [pi0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi0) should be the corresponding one for the Zero NOT [pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero). IMHO.

Comment: But "zero" is closer to the brand. The Foundation calls it "Pi Zero" not "Pi 0" compared to the "Pi Model 2" which is not called "Pi Two". So it might still be a valid idea to go for [tag:pi-zero]. But since @goldilocks created a synonym we have both.